# Amazon.co.uk Add to Basket URL Parameters for Amazon Vendor Only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, url

I've worked out how to bulk add products to the basket using the URL and change quantity.

Here is an example:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aws/cart/add.html?ASIN.1=B00FKTYH1Y&Quantity.1=1&ASIN.2=B00IAOOAE0&Quantity.2=1&ASIN.3=B00I1E2GB8&Quantity.3=1&ASIN.4=B00A5YQB18&Quantity.4=1&ASIN.5=B003CKBAGI&Quantity.5=1

However this uses the seller who currently has the Add to Basket. I want to use Amazon.co.uk only.

I know usually by adding in the search results: &emi=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE

You will get Amazon.co.uk search results. But this doesn't seem to work for add to basket.

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Note at the moment they all might add to basket from amazon because amazon has the buy now button. So you will need to find a asin which is sold by amazon and third party, but third party is currently got the buy now.

For example this clock ASIN:

B000ZJ3KIA

So if we create the URL:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aws/cart/add.html?ASIN.1=B000ZJ3KIA&Quantity.1=1

How can we force that to pick Amazon?

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't that clear.. from what I understand everyone can create urls like that to add an item to the cart and then redirect to Amazon. If you want to make sure you end up with a specific SELLER, you'll need to work with OfferListingId instead of ASIN's. Go to the product page, make sure you pick the correct seller and look at the source code for the OfferListingId. Make it OfferListingId.x (instead of ASIN.x) of course.